Autocomplete for built in JavaScript functions not working inside custom made functions
I’m experiencing an issue with IntelliSense (autocomplete) in my JavaScript development environment (VS Code). Specifically, autocomplete for built-in JavaScript methods like slice() is not working inside custom functions. While the function itself executes correctly, IntelliSense fails to provide suggestions or autocomplete options when typing . after the variable name within the function. However, the same methods work and are suggested as expected when used outside of custom functions.
See example images:
enter image description here
enter image description here
Tried renaming variables to avoid conflicts with built-in JavaScript names.
Restarted VS Code.
Created a new file to test if the issue persists.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and/or error messages need to be included in your question as text, not as pictures of text.  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Specifically for the [pictures of] code shown... Where/how are those variables defined/assigned?  If the code makes it clear that something is an array, intellisense is likely to suggest array methods.  But if a particular variable has no such information and can be anything at all, I don't see how intellisense would know that you expect it to be an array.  This may be a good time to start looking into TypeScript.

In addition to @David 's comment, if you don't want to use Typescript, VSCode's Intellisense understands code annotations via JSDoc comments as well.
